# Why aren't numerical solutions (Euler method) to Lotka-Volterra system (all parameters equal to 1) periodic?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Why aren't numerical solutions (Euler method) to Lotka-Volterra system (all parameters equal to 1) periodic?

Any help or just tips will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: No reason why it shouldn't. It is just that Euler's Method is the most primitive numerical method for solving differential equations. So it might need smaller step sizes.

Comment: You should really give some more details about what you did, and maybe showing some of the numerical soultions you got. Otherwise somebody probably will close this ...

Comment: @grdgfgr Actually, there is no reason why numerical solution should be periodic. Unless some extraordinary coincidence happens, it will not be -- no matter what the method or step size.

Comment: @Yes do you mean it as it will not be able to sustain periodicity indefinitely? What I meant to say was that it would imitate periodicity for a duration depending on the stepsize and the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact solutions to Volterra-Lotka are convex, almost circular curves. The explicit method follows the tangents of these curves, which means that every step changes to a more outward curve. The implicit method is the exact reverse, each step changes the level to a more inward curve.

You need higher-order explicit methods for better preservation of the first integral (dynamical invariants of the system), or implicit methods of at least order 2.

See the introductory texts to numerical methods by Hairer et al., these have nice graphical demonstrations of these principles.

- http://www.dmae.upct.es/~amat/simplecticos2.pdf
- http://na.uni-tuebingen.de/~lubich/chap1.pdf

---

The Euler method has an error $\sim th$ for middle ranges of $t$ and $\sim e^{Lt}h$ for larger values of $t$. This error in the state propagates to dynamical invariants of the state.

Higher order methods drastically reduce these errors for similar step lengths. Some methods like the implicit midpoint method preserve dynamical invariants to a higher order than the error order of the state. Due to the time symmetry of the implicit midpoint method, there are only even degree terms in $h$ in the error function, so the even if the trajectory error is $\sim th^2$, the invariant diverges only $\sim th^4$ from a constant. This gives seemingly periodic numerical solutions for very long time intervals.

Comment: So the curve being convex is the problem. This is the answer I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: Nah, Euler being first order and thus preserving (resp. diverging from) invariants of the system only to first order is the problem. Being convex just provides a clear pattern for the divergence.